# Interpolation and Interpolationerror - how to compute ?

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, fixed-point-iteration

I want to compute the greatest $a>0$ for given $\epsilon>0$ such that $$max_{x\in [-a,a]}|f(x)-p_2(x)| < \epsilon$$   where $a$ is the distance between two grid points and the maximum is the interpolation error. $p_2$ is the interpolation polynomial of $f(x)=sin(2x)$ with $p_2(x)=\frac{sin(a)}{a}x$

We know that $$max_{x\in [0,a]}|f(x)-p_2(x)| <\omega_n(x)   max_{\xi\in[0;a]} \frac{f^{n+1}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}$$
With $\omega(x)$ being knot polynom.

Because as JeanMarie mentioned we just look at the inervall $[0,a]$, I got:
$\omega(x)=x(x-a)=x^2-xa$

$max_{\xi\in[0;h]} \frac{f^{n+1}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}$=$max_{\xi\in[0;a]} \frac{4}{3}cos(2\xi)$
$\Rightarrow$ Maximum in $\xi=0$

Now shall I take an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ and find the greatest $a>0$ ?

Comment: You don't say what you mean by $p_n(x)$. Moreover the origin of $g'(x)=2cos(2x)- \frac{1}{a}sin(2a)$ is quite mysterious...

Comment: A general comment about polynomial approximations is that a straightforward way is to make interval [-a,a] into [-1,1] and use Chebyshev approximation ($T_n$ polynomials). It works even to find an unknown $a$ ...

Comment: @JeanMarie I edited thanks.

Comment: Is $p_2$ a function of $a$? It sounds like $p_2$ is the interpolation polynomial of $f$ at the points $-a,0,a$ from context.

Comment: You say "the" interpolation polynomial ; first of all, what is the degree of $p_2$ ? 2?

Comment: @Ian: yes,that's what I meant

Comment: @JeanMarie: $p_2$ should be like $p_2=ax²+bx+c$ - I got $p_2=xsin(-2a)2/a$

Comment: As you approximate an odd function $y=\sin(2x)$ by a linear function $y=kx$ (thus also odd), restrict your study to $[0,a]$, and make a graphical representation... it often help.